# Append blank results to end in alphabetical order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I would like to return a list of items by alphabetical order, but have the "empty" results append to the end as opposed to appearing at the beginning. Is there a way to do this using the MySQL ORDER statement, or perhaps another way?

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE status = 'active' ORDER BY lastName;
```

What I get:

```
Jason
Peter
Frank Asimov
Reda Banks
Scott Sorrel
```

What I want:

```
Frank Asimov
Reda Banks
Scott Sorrel
Jason 
Peter
```

Comment: Empty means null or empty string?

Comment: Empty means empty string

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM persons WHERE status = 'active' 
 ORDER BY case when ifnull(lastName,'') = '' then 1 else 0 end, lastname
```

Comment: +1. You can improve it: `case when nullif(lastName,'') is null then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: what if the entry isn't null, but just empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the FIELD statement. It goes something like that:

```
SELECT [...] ORDER BY FIELD(lastName, '') DESC
```

This will either append all the empty-string lastnames to the end. If instead of empty strings, you have NULL on your database:

```
SELECT [...] ORDER BY FIELD(lastName, NULL) DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe all you need is to `ORDER BY` the `firstName`:

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE status = 'active' ORDER BY lastName, firstName
```